# Why SSL certificate(issued through AWS Certificate Manager) fails to apply on Apache2 server running on EC2 Linux instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager, aws-route53

I have generated a public SSL certificate through AWS Certificate Manager. I want to use this certificate for my web applications running on EC2 instance under Apache Server for HTTPS Access.

I have followed following steps to configure the SSL for my EC2 instance using CloudFront and Route 53.

[Routing traffic to an Amazon CloudFront distribution by using your domain name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html)

[How do I configure my CloudFront distribution to use an SSL/TLS certificate?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/install-ssl-cloudfront)

[Why can't I configure ACM certificates for my website hosted on an EC2 instance?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/configure-acm-certificates-ec2)

EC2 instance is running on Linux server. Apache and Django server are running inside docker container and accessible over http: port 80 and https: port 443, django server running on 8015 port over ssl.

After configuration I am able to get the web page over http but over https it is not reachable.

Thanks in advance!